# Centre using CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I have a menu and I want to centre it using CSS.

Current code:

```
.menu {
    margin:10px 0 10px 20px;
    float:right;
}
.menu li {
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;
    border-left:1px solid #FFF;
    border-right:1px solid #DDD;
    float:left;
}
.menu li.first {
    border-left:none;
}
```

What would I add/change/remove to make the menu display centre and not left/right? thanks!

Comment: You mean the whole menu or the elements inside the menu?

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to do this is to set both the left and the right margin to `auto` and give the element a fixed width:

```
.menu {
    width: 500px; // or whatever
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The W3C [recommends](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#hc3) that if you want your `.menu` element to be closely fit around the content, you may want to use absolute positioning and 50% margins instead, like this:

```
.menu {
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

You can see how this works on the W3C page. However, the first method is more common (and readable).

Comment: @Bluestinct Try taking out the `float` rule from your `li` declaration. Does it still not work?